# Add item to an Array 2D using LINQ

Tags: .net, array, linq, vb.net, generics

I've wrote a generic function to add an item to an Array 2D

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub Add_Item_Array_2D(ByRef Array_2D As String(,), _
                              ByVal Items As String())

    Dim tmp_array(Array_2D.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, Array_2D.GetUpperBound(1)) As String

    For x As Integer = 0 To Array_2D.GetUpperBound(0)
        tmp_array(x, 0) = Array_2D(x, 0)
        tmp_array(x, 1) = Array_2D(x, 1)
    Next

    For x As Integer = 0 To Items.Count - 1
        tmp_array(tmp_array.GetUpperBound(0), x) = Items(x)
    Next

    Array_2D = tmp_array

End Sub
```

The code works, but I want to know if can be improved using Array.Resize method of LINQ extensions.

This is an usage example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.shown

    ' Create Array 2D (2,2)
    Dim MyArray As String(,) = _
    {{"Item 0,0", "Item 0,1"}, {"Item 1,0", "Item 1,1"}, {"Item 2,0", "Item 2,1"}}

    ' Add Item
    Add_Item_Array_2D(MyArray, {"Item 3,0", "Item 3,1"})

    ' Loop over the Array 2D
    For x As Integer = 0 To MyArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        MsgBox(String.Format("Array 2D {1},0: {2}{0}Array 2D {1},1: {3}", Environment.NewLine, _
                            x, MyArray(x, 0), MyArray(x, 1)))
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple nitpicks:

- **Try to stick to *PascalCasing* for method names**. Using `_` underscores not only makes your method names look rather messy, the underscore is conventionally used for event handler methods (like `Form1_Load`, i.e. `object_event`).
- **Consistency is king**. Your two snippets aren't consistent as far as parameter naming goes: you're using *PascalCasing* in your top example, and *camelCasing* in the bottom one. **Pick one, stick to it.**
- The term **generic** [has a specific meaning in the .net world](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235246.aspx). That's not a *generic* function. *General-purpose*, maybe?

---

A quick Google search didn't yield much interesting results in VB.net, but [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539620/1188513) has a decent C# version of the code - and it just happens to be an actual *generic* method:

> Most methods in the array class only work with one-dimensional arrays, so you have to perform the copy manually:
>
> ```
> T[,] ResizeArray<T>(T[,] original, int rows, int cols)
> {
>     var newArray = new T[rows,cols];
>     int minRows = Math.Min(rows, original.GetLength(0));
>     int minCols = Math.Min(cols, original.GetLength(1));
>     for(int i = 0; i < minRows; i++)
>         for(int j = 0; j < minCols; j++)
>            newArray[i, j] = original[i, j];
>     return newArray;
> }
> ```

Now I know this isn't VB, but an *array* is an *array* regardless of the language, so I strongly recommend you take a look at the SO answer, as it goes in much more details than I'd care to quote over here.

**Bottom line: You cannot use Array.Resize() with multidimensional arrays**.

Answer (score 1):

> **Bottom line**: You cannot use `Array.Resize()` with multidimensional
>   arrays.

On the other hand, a 2-D list eliminates the resizing altogether.`List(Of List(Of String))` adding items is as easy as the following:

```
Private Sub Add_Item_Array_2D(ByRef Array_2D As List(Of List(Of String)), _
                              ByVal Items As String())
    Array_2D.Add(New List(Of String)(Items))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To resize multidimentional arrays without using any lists, read the [MSN documentation for `Array.Resize<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx).